# Find the last window created in Maya?

Tags: python, maya

I was wondering if there is any way to find the name of the last window created in Maya, knowing that I can't add any information to the window itself before that... I checked in both the `cmds` and API but couldn't find anything. Maybe in PyQt but I don't know much about it.

I'm looking for any solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with, it's surely not the "cleanest" solution but it works!

```
# List all the currently opened windows
uisBefore = cmds.lsUI (wnd = True)

# Execute the function which may or may not create a window
func(*args, **kwargs)

# List all the opened windows again
uisAfter = cmds.lsUI (wnd = True)

# Find all the windows that were opened after executing func()
newUIs = [ui for ui in uisAfter if ui not in uisBefore]
```

Comment: @DrWeeny Oh, how come?

Comment: lsUI in maya 2016 is filtered by "created using ELF UI commands".  So for finding PyQt window, you have to loop through all children of maya (to find QDialogs). Here is a link : http://tech-artists.org/forum/showthread.php?6211-lsUI-command-doesn-t-show-pyqt-window

Answer (score 1):

you can work with something like a close callback, save the needed information and restore it again

```
def restoreLayout(self):
    """
    Restore the layout of each widget
    """
    settings=self.settings
    try:
        self.restoreGeometry(settings.value("geometry").toByteArray())
        self.restoreState(settings.value("windowState").toByteArray())
        size=settings.value('fontSize').toFloat()[0]
        self.setFontSize(size)
    except:
        pass

def saveLayout(self):
    """
    Save the layout of each widget
    Save the main window id to your data base
    """
    settings=self.settings
    settings.setValue("geometry", self.saveGeometry())
    settings.setValue("windowState", self.saveState())
    settings.setValue("fontSize", app.font().pointSize())

def closeEvent(self, event):
    QtGui.QMainWindow.closeEvent(self, event)
    self.saveLayout()
```

a simple case/idea to save tha main win_id and a child button_id:

```
from functools import partial
import json
def close_ui(*args):
    win_id = args[0]
    if cmds.window(win_id, exists=True):
       cmds.deleteUI(win_id, window=True)
       with open('dataBase/ui/uidata.json', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(args, outfile)
win = {}
win["main_win"] = cmds.window()
cmds.columnLayout()
cmds.text( label='closing it' )
win["btn"] = cmds.button( label='Close')
cmds.button(win["btn"],e=True, command=partial(close_ui, win["main_win"], win["btn"]))
cmds.showWindow(win["main_win"])
```

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is actually that I can't create the window, I just need to find its name from... nothing. I just know that the window exists. That's why it's tricky.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a window with the `window` command, you'll get back the name of the window you just created:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
w = cmds.window()
c= cmds.columnLayout()

def who_am_i(*_):
    print "window is", w

b = cmds.button('push', c=who_am_i)
cmds.showWindow(w)
```

If for some reason you don't own the code that creates the window:

```
existing_windows = set(cmds.lsUI(type = 'window'))
// make your window here
new_windows = list(set(cmds.lsUI(type = 'window') - existing_windows))
```